# What are some excellent HTML 5, CSS 3 and JavaScript blogs?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm following Ajaxian, but I'm wondering if there are other awesome blogs about HTML 5, CSS 3, JavaScript and such?

Comment: You'll get more answers on http://doctype.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[CSS3.info](http://www.css3.info/) is pretty good for finding out about the latest happenings in the CSS world.

[A List Apart](http://www.alistapart.com/) usually has great articles regarding web development (not specifically HTML5, CSS3, JavaScript).

Answer (score 5):

Some Javascript blogs from my Google Reader

- [http://www.davidflanagan.com/](https://davidflanagan.com/)
- [http://dreaminginjavascript.wordpress.com](https://dreaminginjavascript.wordpress.com/)
- [http://www.dustindiaz.com](https://www.dustindiaz.com)
- [http://www.stevesouders.com/blog](https://www.stevesouders.com/blog/)
- [http://james.padolsey.com](https://j11y.io/)
- [http://ejohn.org](https://johnresig.com/)
- [http://www.nczonline.net/blog](https://humanwhocodes.com/blog/)
- [http://webreflection.blogspot.com/](https://webreflection.blogspot.com/)

Comment: +1 I just spent an hour on Dreaming in Javascript.  Great recommendation!

Answer (score 4):

It is not specific to HTML5 and CSS3, but it is a very helpful blog :

http://perfectionkills.com/

It deals with good practices for the web in general and performance improvements of web apps.

Answer (score 4):

[Dive into HTML5](http://fortuito.us/diveintohtml5/)

24 ways (you'll have to wait until December for 24 more articles, but read the old ones): http://24ways.org/

Answer (score 3):

[Ajaxian](http://ajaxian.com/) is probably the best news source.

[Smashing magazine](http://www.smashingmagazine.com) also publishes interesting articles about HTML/CSS techniques and web design in general.

Answer (score 3):

Me and a lot of people I work with periodically check [Chris West's Blog](http://gotochriswest.com/blog/).  His code is pretty good and he seems to always have new ways of looking at things that you wouldn't normally think of.  He also developed a customizable JavaScript library called [jPaq](http://jpaq.org/) so he seems to know his stuff.  One thing to note is that he seems to love and be best in JavaScript, but he does refer to some CSS3 and HTML5 things.

Answer (score 2):

http://24ways.org has some really nice introductory articles for CSS3 features.

Answer (score 1):

If you want up close and personal information on what is going on with HTML 5, I guess you should go directly to the *source* and read [WHATWG Blog](http://blog.whatwg.org/)

Answer (score 1):

For HTML5 I would also recommend [HTML5 Doctor](http://html5doctor.com/).

Answer (score 1):

[cssBeauty](http://www.cssbeauty.com/)

Answer (score 1):

[ScriptAndStyle](http://www.scriptandstyle.com) has a good rotation of CSS HTML and Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

i have google alerts for html 5 OR css 3

Answer (score 0):

- [CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/) is excellent (all
  kinds of CSS);
- [Nettuts](http://net.tutsplus.com/) has a lot
  of useful tutorials on all kinds of
  web-related areas;
- [Soh Tanaka](http://www.sohtanaka.com/) -
  mainly Javascript-focused, seems to have
  gone quiet recently though.